# Is the solution set of a linear program always bounded?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, polytopes

> Let $$\max\left\{c^T \cdot x \mid A \cdot x \leq b, x \geq
> 0\right\}$$ be an arbitrary linear program and let $M$ be its solution set. Is $M$ always bounded?

I think the solution set of linear programming problem is not always bounded because let's say the linear programming problem is infeasible, so then $M$ is empty. Is that enough of reasoning? It can also be unbounded I think if the value of its objective function can be made arbitrarily large so in that case it would be unbounded since  its optimum value is $+ \infty$. And if this is not the case then the LP is bounded but as we see this is not always the case. So the statement is false, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If $M$ is empty, it is bounded.
- Also note that, $M$ is a solution set, not a linear programming problem.
- The statement is indeed false, here is a way to make $M$ unbounded. We let $A=0$ and $x=0$ and $c=0$. Hence $M=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n|x \ge 0\}$. It is unbounded. To see it clearly note that $ke \in M$, where $k \ge 0$ can be made arbitrarily large and $e$ is the all ones vector.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! Just one question, by "all ones vector" you mean a vector filled with only $1$'s, right?

Comment: yes, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is $(1,1)^T$.